# Neo4j not starting with older data store version

Tags: neo4j

I tried to run Neo4j community edition using a db folder which I'm using for my project. When i tried to run Neo4j it gave me this error:

> Failed to start Neo4j with an older data store version. To enable
>   automatic upgrade, please set configuration parameter
>   "dbms.allow_format_migration=true"

After changing the config file and uncommenting the above mentioned parameter i got the following error:

> Starting Neo4j failed: Component
>   'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@7594f97a' was
>   successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached
>   cause exception.

Can anyone tell me what do I need to do to make it work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you check the logs?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same situation a few weeks ago. There are three situations as far as I know.

1) You have same plugins for both location */plugins* and  */plugins*. Remove plugins from */plugins* location.

2) You current Neo4j version is different than the original database was developed. You need same or newer CE version.

3) The APOC plugin (if installed) and Neo4j versions aren't matching.

If you share what log says then others might be able to give more detailed help.